# Salvar no Banco de dados Checkbox

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter-3

Estou em dúvida em como salvar no banco de dados um checkbox. Como salvar uma sequencia de números para saber quais opções foram selecionadas. Da forma atual so salva a ultima opção selecionada. Existe alguma forma de salvar como "1234" ou "24" por exemplo para saber as opções que o usuário selecionou?

```
<div class="row narrow p-0">
<div class="col-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="star" for="dias_selecionados">Quais dias deseja?</label><label class="text-danger" >  *Somente os dias desejados</label>
        <div class="mt-1 py-1 px-2 border border-festival rounded">
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input m-0" type="checkbox" name="dias_selecionados" id="1" value="1" autocomplete="off"/>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="1">dia 1</label>
                <?php if (isset($_POST['dias_selecionados']) && $_POST['dias_selecionados'] == '1')?>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input m-0" type="checkbox" name="dias_selecionados" id="2" value="2" autocomplete="off"/>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="2">Dia 2</label>
                <?php if (isset($_POST['dias_selecionados']) && $_POST['dias_selecionados'] == '2')?>

            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input m-0" type="checkbox" name="dias_selecionados" id="3" value="3" autocomplete="off"/>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="3">Dia 3</label>
                <?php if (isset($_POST['dias_selecionados']) && $_POST['dias_selecionados'] == '3')?>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input m-0" type="checkbox" name="dias_selecionados" id="4" value="4" autocomplete="off"/>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="4">Dia 4</label>
                <?php if (isset($_POST['dias_selecionados']) && $_POST['dias_selecionados'] == '4')?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Avalie a utilização do tipo de dados `json`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O mais fácil seria você criar uma coluna no banco de dados para representar a seleção de cada check box.

Do contrário, se você não tiver a opção de criar uma coluna no BD você poderia adotar uma combinação binária.

0000 - Nenhum check box selecionado
0001 - Primeiro check box selecionado
0010 - Segundo check box selecionado
0011 - PRimeiro e segundo check box selecionado
0100 - Terceiro check box selecionado
... e por ai vai

Answer (score 0):

Faz assim... coloca uma classe no checkbox, igual para todos e recupera o valor (id).

No javascript faça assim quando for enviar para o php via post.

```
<input class="form-check-input m-0 dias_selecionados" type="checkbox" name="dias_selecionados" id="1" value="1" autocomplete="off"/>

var check_lista = [];
// aqui vc sabe quantos checks dessa classe tem para verificar, e se estiver com Check, então, recupera o valor ou o ID
for(var i=0; i < $('.dias_selecionados:checked').length; ++i){
    check = $('.dias_selecionados:checked')[i].value;
    check_lista.push(check);
}
```

assim vc guarda em um array usando o push, ou se achar melhor, você pode concatenar em uma String. Ai é com você.